# Windows Server 2008 R2 (Clustered) - Time Sync Issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Good afternoon,

I'd like to express a question that hopefully can get an answer. I have 2 clustered Windows Server 2008 R2 Server under the same domain controller.

However, as weird it might be , both of them have different time (for seconds), when I have to reboot them for maintenance I got to manually adjust time on both servers. 
When looking at the NTP Server by using (net time /querysntp) I got the same server on both.

What would be your suggestions/tips in order to get the time properly sync in the servers? They're critical for operation and heavy time-based for the applications they used.

All answers and help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Virtualization involved anywhere?   Also are the clustered servers pointing to a completely different time server on the domain unrelated to the two servers In the cluster.  is this 3rd Server that is the time server an AD Server or "DC".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Those are not virtual server and yeah.. The time server pointed by the clustered server is unrelated to both servers